# Raising the undo/history limit in Redcar? Alternatively, any comparable text-editors to redcar?

Tags: redcar

I started using Redcar a couple days ago as my primary text editor for programming on my Ubuntu machine. It's definitely a buggy software, and it's obvious that it's still in development, but overall I like it more than anything else I've come across. That said, I just discovered that I apparently can't do any more than 10 or so undos with the software. Even worse, I wasn't able to figure out any way to change this limit. This is kind of a dealbreaker for me, since I routinely write lots of code that I then choose to revert to something I had only a minute earlier.

Does anybody know if there is any way to raise this limit? Alternatively, does anybody know any other comparable text-editors for Linux? One of the most important features for me that any software I use needs to have is the ability to show me where a partner bracelet/bracket/parenthesis is when I move the cursor (or rather, whatever the keyboard equivalent of the cursor is called) onto it. I'm writing software that uses lots of callbacks, nested if statements, and nested loops, so I need to be able to easily tell where corresponding structures are in my code.

Best, and thanks in advance for any responses,
Sami